# Where do I get a list of Build.MODEL names for all Android devices?

Tags: android, list, build, model

hi i am looking for a list of constants android build.model someone could say as getting some list? my main problem is with the flash on samsung galaxy ace I can not do it if I havent the build.model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just Google for the model-names that you need.

**For the Samsung Galaxy Ace, its "S5830".**

Furthermore, there is a github project focusing on this topic.

**https://github.com/mataanin/android-devices**

Comment: that github link looks unmaintained as of July 2016

Answer (score 9):

Google Play have one of the most complete lists available as a PDF at:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB

and in CSV at:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6154891?hl=en

For the record Meetup also have a list available at:

https://github.com/meetup/android-device-names